# Polymer - cloneNode including __data

Tags: polymer, clonenode

I am using the library [dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula) for doing some drag & drop stuff.

Dragula internally uses `cloneNode(true)` to create a copy of the dragged element that will be appended to the body to show the preview image while dragging.

Unfortunately, if dragging a polymer element, the bound data get's not cloned. By consequence the contents of the dragged element (e.g. `<div>[[someString]]</div>`) are empty.

Is there a solution for this?

I actually do not need the data to be bound for my element, it is just a "read-only" element that displays some data that does not change after being initialized. Is there maybe a way to somehow "resolve" the strings to the html without being bound anymore?

Thank you already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution myself. You have to override the `cloneNode` method inside the polymer class:

```
cloneNode(deep) {
  let cloned = super.cloneNode(deep);
  for (let prop in MyClass.properties) {
    cloned[prop] = this[prop];
  }
  return cloned;
}
```